# files and binary formatter

Tags: c#, file

I want to ask how to create and write a text file using binary formatter I have written the below code but I have an exception.
the exception is :
file can not been access because it is has been used by another process.

and my code  creates two files one is with extension ".txt" and the other without any extension.

what should I do? 
Is there another way to create a text  file ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    [Serializable]
    class contact
    {



        string name;
        string address;
        string phonenumber;
        string emailaddress;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name + "   " + address + "   " + phonenumber + "  " + emailaddress;
        }

        public void AddContent(string cname, string caddress, string cphone, string cemail)
        {
            name = cname;
            address = caddress;
            phonenumber = cphone;
            emailaddress = cemail;

            FileStream file = new FileStream("contact.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            contact person = new contact();
            person.name = cname;
            person.address = caddress;
            person.phonenumber = cphone;
            person.emailaddress = cemail;
            bin.Serialize(file, person);
            file.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(" added sucefully");


        }//end of fun add
```

}

Comment: **What does the exception say**? Did you read it?

Comment: file can not been access because it is been used by another process and it creates two files one is with extension ".txt" and the other without any extension.

Comment: No. `FileStream` Creates only the File that you Specify. I guess you are Already created that file otherwhere in your code and does not close the handle to it. In another post i already send you an Code snipped that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception has nothing to do with the BinaryFormatter but instead with the fact that you are not disposing of the FileStream properly. Always wrap streams in a using block:

```
 using(FileStream file = new FileStream("contact.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
 {
    //code here
 }
```

This guarantees that the stream underneath is closed and the unmanaged resources are freed. In your case in particular, it seems that the OS still has a lock to the file you are attempting to create and the second time you run your code throws the exception about your file `being  used by another process`

Answer (score 0):

```
 file can not been access because it is has been used by another process.
```

Is it possible that you may have in advertantly opened this file and its still open in a text window?